# Hive Error starting MRAppMaster java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

We have a problem when we trying to load data from one hive table to another hive (land to raw)
All answers and issues that I've found was not for our case (such example like change version of guava if it has difference in versions - but that's ok in our case)

````
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1358) ~[hadoop-common-3.1.1.3.1.4.0-315.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1339) ~[hadoop-common-3.1.1.3.1.4.0-315.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1690) [hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-3.1.1.3.1.4.0-315.jar:?]
2021-07-01T09:25:57,322 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil - Exiting with status 1: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
2021-07-01T09:25:57,326 INFO [shutdown-hook-0] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster - MRAppMaster received a signal. Signaling RMCommunicator and JobHistoryEventHandler.```
````

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base` is definitely a Guava problem

Comment: Not Guava - we tested this hypothesis already

Comment: Alright, well, the stacktrace doesn't lie. The version might not be the problem. You need to extract the JAR to actually look what methods **are available**

Answer (score 1):

We solved that by deleting one of an unused clickhouse library file in a list of jar drivers for jdbc connection - clickhouse-jdbc-0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar